# Example of the Extreme Value Theorem not holding over the rational numbers

Tags: real-analysis

I'm reading some [notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/2400FULL.pdf), and on page 11 the author uses the function f(x):[0,2], f(x) = 1/(x^2 - 2) over the rational numbers to show that the extreme value theorem doesn't hold(over the rationals).

I'm wondering if it's correct to even apply the extreme value theorem for this function - isn't one of the requirements that the function be bounded(which this one isn't)?

Apologies for the lack of formatting, I have no knowledge about that (yet).

Comment: A much easier example would be $f:[0,\sqrt{2}]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=x^2$...

Comment: On page 111 of the notes you linked, the only condition is that $f$ be continuous on a closed finite interval.  That $f$ is bounded is part of the *conclusion* of the theorem, not a requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, that example does work. But if it makes you feel better, think about $\sin(x)$ on, say, $[0,2]$. The maximum of $\sin$ occurs at $x= \pi/2, 5\pi/2$, etc., none of which are rational. You can show that $\sin(x)$ has no maximum on the rational numbers in $[0,2]$, since you can plug in rational values of $x$ arbitrarily close to $\pi/2$ and the $y$-values approach 1, but never get there.

Comment: Ok - I think I understand. But the example function makes a jump, although at an irrational number. I guess the limit and derivative exist at any given point between 0 and 2, but it just seems intuitively wrong that a function with a jump is continuous..? Thanks a lot in any case!

Comment: Well, that's exactly the point the notes are trying to make about why we don't do calculus on the rational numbers. On the real numbers, continuous functions look like nice, non-jumpy curves. But if you restrict to the rational numbers, all of a sudden, even continuous functions make little jumps all over the place. Those jumps are why theorems that should be true about continuous functions don't really work on the rationals.